# Expression is undefined when try to call java method in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

i try call java method from Freemarker template:

my data class:

```
public class SimpleObject {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    public SimpleObject(String id, String name) {
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

my service class:

```
public class MainService {

    List<SimpleObject> getAll() {
        SimpleObject so = new SimpleObject("1", "Maksim");
        List<SimpleObject> sol = new ArrayList<SimpleObject>();
        sol.add(so);
        return sol;
    }
}
```

transforming code:

```
MainService ms = new MainService();
Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
root.put("results", ms.getAll());
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate(".test.ftl");
temp.process(root, out);
System.out.println(out.getBuffer().toString());
```

.test.ftl

```
<#list mc.getAll() as result>

  result.getName()

</#list>
```

Error:

```
Expression mc is undefined on line 3, column 8 in .test.ftl.
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> list mc.getAll() as result [on line 3, column 1 in .test.ftl]
----------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because in your model `root` there is not `mc`.

In this case since you are putting `results` into `root` instead of calling `mc.getAll()` in your freemarker you can use `root`

So

```
<#list restults as result>
```

Or you need to add the `MainService` instance `ms` to the model(`root`) with key `mc`

```
Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
root.put("mc", ms);
```

Comment: I try: `root.put("ms", ms);` and `<#list ms.getAll() as result>`. But get same error.

Comment: Thanks, problem in my test class declaration: `List<SimpleObject> getAll()`, set public identifier: `public List<SimpleObject> getAll()`